# Restricting Columns from a union query

Tags: sql

I have a union query which retreives information from two differant requests compares them and displays YES,NO,NA based on the comparison in a third row.

**Below is my SQL query**

```
SELECT CAST(RR.reqestno AS VARCHAR(MAX)) reqestno,
CAST(RR.receiveddate AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS receiveddate,
CAST(RR.rptcomments AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS rptcomments,
CAST(RR.reportfrequency AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS reportfrequency,
CAST(RR.schedule AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS schedule,
CAST(RR.schedulebasedon AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS schedulebasedon,
CAST(RR.clmsrvdtfrom AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmsrvdtfrom,
CAST(RR.clmsrvdtthru AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmsrvdtthru,
CAST(RR.clmpddtfrom AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmpddtfrom,
CAST(RR.clmpddtthru AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmpddtthru,
CAST(RR.customer AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS customer
from REPORT_REQUEST RR 
where RR.reqestno = xxxxxx
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(RR.reqestno AS VARCHAR(MAX)) reqestno,
CAST(RR.receiveddate AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS receiveddate,
CAST(RR.rptcomments AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS rptcomments,
CAST(RR.reportfrequency AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS reportfrequency,
CAST(RR.schedule AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS schedule,
CAST(RR.schedulebasedon AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS schedulebasedon,
CAST(RR.clmsrvdtfrom AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmsrvdtfrom,
CAST(RR.clmsrvdtthru AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmsrvdtthru,
CAST(RR.clmpddtfrom AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmpddtfrom,
CAST(RR.clmpddtthru AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clmpddtthru,
CAST(RR.customer AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS customer
from REPORT_REQUEST RR 
where RR.reqestno = yyyyyy
UNION ALL
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN A.reqestno = B.reqestno THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'  END as reqestno,
      CASE WHEN A.receiveddate = B.receiveddate THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as receiveddate,
      CASE  WHEN A.rptcomments is null and B.rptcomments is null then 'NA' WHEN A.rptcomments = B.rptcomments THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END rptcomments,
      CASE WHEN A.reportfrequency = B.reportfrequency THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as reportfrequency,
      CASE WHEN A.schedule = 'NONE' and B.schedule = 'NONE' THEN 'NA'WHEN A.schedule = B.schedule THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as schedule,
      CASE WHEN A.schedulebasedon = 'NONE' and B.schedulebasedon = 'NONE' THEN 'NA' WHEN A.schedulebasedon = B.schedulebasedon THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as schedulebasedon,
      CASE WHEN A.clmsrvdtfrom is null and B.clmsrvdtfrom is Null Then 'NA' WHEN A.clmsrvdtfrom = B.clmsrvdtfrom THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as clmsrvdtfrom,
      CASE WHEN A.clmsrvdtthru is null and B.clmsrvdtthru is null then 'NA' WHEN A.clmsrvdtthru = B.clmsrvdtthru THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as clmsrvdtthru,
      CASE WHEN A.clmpddtfrom is Null and B.clmpddtfrom is null then 'NA' WHEN A.clmpddtfrom = B.clmpddtfrom THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as clmpddtfrom,
      CASE WHEN A.clmpddtthru is null and B.clmpddtthru is null then 'NA' WHEN A.clmpddtthru = B.clmpddtthru THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as clmpddtthru,
      CASE WHEN A.customer = B.customer THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as customer

FROM
            (SELECT  reqestno,receiveddate,rptcomments,reportfrequency,schedule,schedulebasedon,clmsrvdtfrom,
clmsrvdtthru,clmpddtfrom,clmpddtthru,customer  FROM REPORT_REQUEST WHERE reqestno = xxxxxx) AS A
INNER JOIN
                 (SELECT  reqestno,receiveddate,rptcomments,reportfrequency,schedule,schedulebasedon,clmsrvdtfrom,
clmsrvdtthru,clmpddtfrom,clmpddtthru,customer  FROM REPORT_REQUEST WHERE reqestno = yyyyyy) AS B
      ON 1 = 1
```

**Question**
How should i edit the above query to make it display only columns that have only a value of 'NO' in the third row after comparing the first two rows and in some way hide the other columns whereever comparison returns YES or NA.I want to see all the 3 rows( 2 rows of data + 1 row of compariosn

Need help please
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you casting everything to varchar(max)?  There has to be a need to do something like that but I can't figure why?  I'd imagine this query runs forever!

Comment: You should probably provide a radical simplification of your query, with sample data, and required output, and a decent explanation of why/how to get the output from the data.  As it is, your SQL is just so big that readers retch and move on to a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you put the UNION query into a sub-query and restrict that.  I'm not going to copy your monster query — please read up on SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — but:

```
 SELECT r.*
   FROM (SELECT Value1, Value2
           FROM SomeWhere
          WHERE SomeColumn = 234
         UNION
         SELECT Value1, Value2
           FROM ElseWhere
          WHERE ElseColumn = 432
        ) AS r
  WHERE Value1 > 37 OR Value2 < 91
```

You may also need to do something with OLAP code; you mention 'third row' which is problematic — SQL is a set-based language and ordering is not natural (but it can be done).

Comment: i dont want to restrict records based on a value but woukld like to restrict the columns that are returned based on a value . With your logic i'm gettig results that i desire

Comment: Are you trying to rewrite the number of columns returned depending on what you find, or on a value passed as a parameter to the query?  If so, you're going to have difficulties unless you use dynamic SQL to write the query with the number of columns you want.  A query has to be describable; one aspect of describing a query is the number of columns that will be returned.  You can't have the data modifying the number of columns that are returned.  You could have a fixed number of columns returned, some of which need to be ignored.

Comment: thank you.I was trying to acheive the  data modifying the number of columns that are returned . Anyway thank you for assisting me

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change the `ON` expression of your `INNER JOIN` to your "NO" conditions connected by `and`.

Comment: what would be the where condition which will restrict the columns with that have returned "YES" .It would be ideal if we can have a restriction there

Comment: You're joining on `1-1` which effectively produces Cartesian Join.  In stead I suggested to look through your `CASE` statements, isolate desired conditions to result in "**NO**" and concatenate them with `and`.  This will restrict your `INNER JOIN`.  It will be producing less rows (not columns). - If I misunderstood your requirements please disregard my answer.